# How do you flip a NIFTI image (.nii) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nifti

I know there are functions imrotate3 and imtransform for doing geometric transformations with .nii files. However, I'm not even sure how they work.

I'm trying the flip the nifti image along the x-axis. Would someone be able to give a detailed explanation of the functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could very well use imrotate3 and such for this, but it could be easier to do it as follows:

Start by reading a NIfTI file, and displaying a coronal slice using the imshow function:

```
V = niftiread('brain.nii');
imshow(V(:, :, 14))
```

Here's how you flip along the x-axis (horizontal direction). If you'd like the other axis, consider flipud - for up down.

```
Vflip = fliplr(V);
```

Now display the same slice again, but for the Vflip volume. Notice that it's flipped as intended.

```
figure, imshow(Vflip(:, :, 14))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the multi-dimensional indexing for this if you want:

```
>> a = reshape( 1:8, [ 2 2 2 ] )
a(:,:,1) =
     1     3
     2     4
a(:,:,2) =
     5     7
     6     8
>> b = a ( end:-1:1, :, : ) 
b(:,:,1) =
     2     4
     1     3
b(:,:,2) =
     6     8
     5     7
```

Mind you, the 1st dimension in Matlab selects the row, so flipping the 1st dimension (`x`?) is displayed on the screen as flipping each 2d plane upside-down.